# Resize / Convert an image from a stream with ImageResizer

Tags: stream, imageresizer

I'm trying to figure out how to convert an image from a stream with ImageResizer (http://imageresizing.net/).

I have tried something like this.

```
Stream s = WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/resources/gfx/unnamed.webp").GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

ImageBuilder.Current.Build(s, "~/resources/gfx/photo3.png", new ResizeSettings("format=png"));
```

But i just get the error

"File may be corrupted, empty, or may contain a PNG image with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels."

When i do

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(Server.MapPath("~/resources/gfx/test.webp")))
using (Stream input = WebRequest.Create("http:///example.com/resources/gfx/unnamed.webp").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()) {
                input.CopyTo(output);
}

ImageBuilder.Current.Build("~/resources/gfx/test.webp", "~/resources/gfx/photo3.png",
                           new ResizeSettings("format=png"));
```

It works fine, am i'm missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that 'output' has not been flushed to disk. .NET 4+ doesn't guarantee the file's actually written to disk just because you disposed the stream.

I assume you have the [ImageResizer.Plugins.WebP](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/webp) plugin installed?